# Offline maps with voice navigation

Tags: android, offline, navigation, openstreetmap

I got my application which will have specific lat and long from start and end location. Based on these information I need to for e.g. call a particular offline map which will give me voice navigation to guide me from my start to end location. I tried google map but it does not have voice navigation. I tried osmand but that does not have any sdk for it to called from my app. Any suggestion?